# How to check the code rules with eclipse?

Tags: coding-style, eclipse

Are there a way to make a check of my code basing on a code rules (code style) with eclipse ?

Is it possible to configure Eclipse for that? Are ther a plugin to do that?

Comment: What you're looking for is static code analysis. I'll assume you're coding java in eclipse, there's a list for static code analysis tools for java on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java

Comment: You could install the CheckStyle plugin and add your own rules.

Comment: pmd also allows for custom rule creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feel yourself comfortable with [writing CheckStyle checks](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html), you can install CheckStyle. Using Eclipse Juno:

- install CheckStyle plugin (Help > Install new Software > Add Repository > http://eclipse-cs.sf.net/update/
- Window > Preferences > CheckStyle > configure new checks

However, unless your style is something *really* fancy, chances are that the standard checks and personalization of same will be more than enough to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) plugin for Eclipse. I've used it.

[Here's how you istall it.](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.4/integrations.html#eclipse)

If you are behind a proxy, you will have to [add your proxy to Eclipse](http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/) since it install plugins from a repository.

You can also instal PMD as a stand-alone utility if you want by downloading the non-plugin package and installing it.